# Cross-platform Mobile Applications

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, visual-studio-cordova

I want to build a cross-platform mobile application.
I read a little about Apache Cordova, as a C# developer, i think this plugin maybe my optimal solution, but i want to hear from an experienced developer who used Cordova with visual studio and developed an application.

Comment: Yes you can go with Cordova it will be a good option. Since you are a C# developer, i suggest Xamarin. Since Cordova runs in web browser, it will give web looks sometime, whereas xamarin runs in native and you will get native look.

Answer (score 0):

You being a C# developer and based on your language knowledge you may start with either of the folowing:

### C# + XAML

Use Visual Studio for Windows Phone and Xamarin for Android and iOS

- If you are C# lover and a hardcore C# developer and want to learn XAML this is a good choice.

### HTML5 + CSS3 + Javascript

Use Visual Studio and install [Visual Studio tools for Cordova](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/cordova-vs.aspx)

- If earlier you were into web development and know about JavaScript this is a good choice.
- Here you can leverage the power of other JavaScript frameworks like Angular, Backbone and Ionic.
- WinRT provides C# like object creation in JavaScript, but in JavaScript way.